# Unbiasedness of OLS estimator

Tags: least-squares, unbiased-estimator

Consider a very simple linear regression model with following assumptions:

1) No assumptions on how $x_i$ is generated (assume random design, not necessarily IID);

2) $\mathbb{E}[\epsilon_i|x_i]=0$, $\forall{i}$;

3) $\epsilon_i$ are uncorrelated across observations;

4) $y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_i + \epsilon_i$.

Consider, usual OLS estimator:

$\hat{\beta_1} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-\bar{x})(y_i-\bar{y})}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-\bar{x})^2}$

Next consider usual decomposition:

$\hat{\beta_1} = \beta_1 + \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-\bar{x})\epsilon_i}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-\bar{x})^2}$

Where $\hat{\beta_1}$ is a usual OLS estimator. Are above assumptions sufficient to prove the unbiasedness of an OLS estimator?

In essence the question boils to the following:

What are the minimal assumptions to have:

$\mathbb{E}[\epsilon_i|x_1,...,x_n]=0$

Solutions:

1) $(x_i, y_i)$ IID across observations - then above assumptions are sufficient (then I do not need to impose that $\epsilon_i$ are uncorrelated across observations );

2 What else would work?

Comment: Take $u_i=x_j$...

Comment: @Xi'an I do not really see what you mean. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Are u_i and \epsilon_i the same thing?

Comment: @SheridanGrant thanks for spotting this, corrected.

Comment: I think the usual assumption for 2 is that $E[\epsilon]=0$, because $E[\epsilon]=E[y|x]$.

Comment: Could you explain in (3) what "uncorrelated across observations" means?